# How to run Meteor project in development mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Currently started work on Meteor and don't know much about meteor debugging. I am running Meteor 1.1.0.2 on my linux server. Meteor by default minifies and combining all css and javascripts available in my lib/css and lib/js folder.

```
$> meteor run --development   #not working
```

**How can I debug any individual CSS or javascript?**

I know each module should have their individual css/js but UX department gave me bunch of css/js files and I need to fix some div and classes.

**Is there any available debug packages in atmosphere through which I can debug css classes and javascript files?**

**Is there any way I can load all css and javascript files individually on my development version?**

Comment: This is weird. As stated in the comments answer of @Ethaan, it should not minify files during the development. Check the web-browser debugger... The normal behaviour is the one you want.

Comment: Do you have `NODE_ENV` set to `production` or something?

Comment: I checked NODE_ENV by $> env command but there are no option like that. I thought meteor only minify and combine css/js in production mode only, which is not currently like for my local development.